# Error on custom javascript button

Tags: javascript, custom-object, custom-button, ajax

Below code should update the `Leadership_Notification_check__c` when the Suite, RedLightReview are not empty, `TOV >= 5000000000` and check field is 0.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}

var Suite= document.getElementById('00Nq00000017vbe_ileinner').innerHTML;
var TOV= document.getElementById('00Nq000000181Wp_ileinner').innerHTML;
var RedLightReview= document.getElementById('00Nq00000017qTB_ileinner').innerHTML;
var ce = new sforce.SObject("Contract_Extract__C");
ce.id = "{!Contract_Extract__c.Id}";
var check = {!Contract_Extract__c.Leadership_Notification_check__c}
if ((TOV >= 5000000000 ||  (Suite != ' ' || Suite != '&nbsp;' ) || (RedLightReview!= ' ' || RedLightReview != '&nbsp;') ) && check === 0) {
       ce.Leadership_Notification_check__c = 1;
       result = sforce.connection.update([ce]);

}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `00Nq00000017vbe_ileinner` using this id are you trying to get the field values?

Comment: basically even though the fields are empty, the check field is updating to 1.

Comment: @Ratan Yes. getting the field values

Comment: @Reddy then you are doing it in wrong way. Salesforce provide you a way to get the record values in custom button .. check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11yzW7sEEHo and check how to use object fields in custom button

Comment: @Ratan you are correct but i tried that as well. Can you tell me how to check what might be the correct condition? if suite and RedLightReview are picklist fields

Comment: @Reddy can you please update your code with way you tried with standard way. let me check what is syntax error you are doing

Comment: {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}

var Suite = '{!Contract_Extract__c.Suite__c}';
var check = '{!Contract_Extract__c.Leadership_Notification_check__c}';
var TOV = '{!Contract_Extract__c.TOV__c}';
var RedLightReview = '{!Contract_Extract__c.Red_Light_Review__c}';

var ce = new sforce.SObject("Contract_Extract__C");
ce.id = "{!Contract_Extract__c.Id}";

alert(TOV);

if (( TOV >= 5000000000 || Suite != ' ' || RedLightReview != ' ' ) && check  == 0){

       ce.Leadership_Notification_check__c = 1;
       result = sforce.connection.update([ce]);
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43077/discussion-between-reddy-and-ratan).